# Determination of electrons flow through the crystal

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, conductors

Talking about doped semiconductors:

Atoms outer shell extends and overlaps with another ones outer shell (the conduction band), right?
So when electrical field is applied to a semiconductor bar (lets say n-type) electrons start to flow in the bar, and then what happens? I know that the electrons in the outer shell/conduction band contribute to electrical current density (usually marked as "J").

But my question is: How is it done? How the outer electrons contribute to electron flow when other electrons flow by or however it is done.

Comment: How is what done? Electrons in the conduction band are free to move. They occupy extended states in the solid (Bloch states). Please clarify your question.

Comment: @JonCuster How electrons move through the crystal lattice? And how do electrons in conduction band contribute to higher electron flow/current?